# appleboy/ssh-action@master - Error Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need to open an ssh session to another server and run some scripts over there.
So decided to use
https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action

The WF is running on a self hosted runner hosted on OCI
Firewall / NSG ports are opened up to the https://registry-1.docker.io host

Facing the following error

Step 1/4 : FROM appleboy/drone-ssh:1.6.10
Trying to pull repository docker.io/appleboy/drone-ssh ...
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Warning: Docker build failed with exit code 1, back off 5.249 seconds before retry.

Code

```
jobs:
  conn_server:
    name: conn_server
    environment: ppm_prod    
    runs-on: ${{ inputs.RUNNER }}
    steps:
      - name: conn_step1
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master 
        with:
          host: xx.yy.zz.oraclevcn.com
          username: oracle
          key: ${{ secrets.SERVER_KEY }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            echo "connection complete : "
            pwd
            echo `hostname` 
            exit
```

Note:
Manually using the same pvt key am able to open an ssh connection to the target server.
Docker is installed on the runner and the daemon is running

Comment: sounds like a firewall problem to me.